# Добавление классов цифрами по порядку в меню wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть вот [этот класс](https://github.com/roikles/Wordpress-Bem-Menu/), который переделывает стандартные названия классов у меню вердпресса под БЭМ. Работает, все ок, только вот как в нем задать каждому пункту меню первого уровня класс-модификатор с цифрой по-порядку, первому задать `menu__item_type_1`, второму `menu__item_type_2` и т.д. В ишью ответили, сказали надо изменять само меню. Подскажите как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

На англоязычной версии [помогли](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30755421/how-to-add-serial-numbers-to-menu-items-in-wordpress?noredirect=1#comment49564836_30755421), нужно просто создать переменную-счетчик (стр. 6), потом в строке 56 конкатенировать уже имеющимся классам текст класса + счетчик и в строке 76 увеличить счетчик если глубина меню равна нулю. Измененный код [тут](https://gist.github.com/podlebar/6da77f557a207e4c675c)